# IndexOutOfRangeException on array

Tags: c#, arrays

```
int[] arr=new int[10]{1,21,32,43,54,65,76,87,98,10};

foreach(var i in arr)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Elements [{0}]:{1}",arr[i],i);              
}
```

I want the output like

```
element[0]: 1
element[1]: 21
...
element[9]: 10
```

by using `foreach` only, but I am getting this error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was
>   outside the bounds of the array.   at Exercise1.Main () <0x41e47d70 +
>   0x0008c> in :0  [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
>   System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the
>   array. at Exercise1.Main () <0x41e47d70 + 0x0008c> in :0

Answer (score 5):

`i` isn't the index, it's the element itselve. In the second iteration of your loop you try to access index 21 `Console.WriteLine("Elements [{0}]:{1}",arr[21],21)` which doesn't exist

change to `for` loop

```
int[] arr = new int[10] { 1, 21, 32, 43, 54, 65, 76, 87, 98, 10 };

for (int i =0;i< arr.Length;i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Elements [{0}]:{1}",i ,arr[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
int j =0;
foreach(var i in arr)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Elements [{0}]:{1}",j,i); 
   j++;             
}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, it helped me to learn.

Answer (score 0):

The `foreach` keyword doesn't return the "index" of the elements. It returns the elements.

```
int[] arr = new int[] {1,21,32,43,54,65,76,87,98,10};

foreach (var el in arr)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Element {0}", el);
}
```

In C# (unlike go) there is no direct construct that returns the `i` index plus the element `arr[i]`. You can have one (`i` using the `for` cycle and from there obtain `arr[i]`) or the other (using `foreach`)

Compare what you wrote with an array of `string`s to see its illogicity:

```
string[] arr = new string[] {"1","21","32","43","54","65","76","87","98","10"};

foreach (var el in arr)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Element {0}", el);
}
```